# Multiple google maps in modal windows (grey boxes resize)

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, resize, zurb-foundation

I've looked on dozens of different topics relating to this but for the life of my cannot get any of them working. I currently have a single page website that has 1 google map and 4 markers. Underneath the map each of these markers has a small html section with information on contact/address etc aswell as a link. This link opens a modal window (foundation 3) with an enlarged google map and only the single Location on it.

The maps that are displayed on these modal windows are just displaying 3/4 of the map as a grey block.

HTML:

```
<a href="#map1" id="modal1-button" data-reveal-id="myModal1" title="location details" class="red-arrow">visit location</a>

    <div id="myModal1" class="reveal-modal large">
      <div id="map-modal1" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var markers = [
     ['Location1', 53.479468, -2.246873, 1],
     ['Location2', 53.483558, -2.239243, 4],
     ['Location3', 53.482900, -2.243132, 5],
     ['Location4', 53.481489, -2.244967, 3];

var map2;

function initializeMaps() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    var optionsMap1 = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.480487, -2.241776),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-modal1"),optionsMap1);

    var image = 'img/wings_icon.png';
    var image2 = 'img/wings_icon_main.png';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
    var marker, i;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var map2LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.483558, -2.239243);
    var map2Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: map2LatLng,
          map: map2,
          icon: image,
          title: 'Wings Manchester Arndale'
    });

    //Main Map Markers Loop
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(pos);
        if (i === 0){
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                icon: image2,
                map: map
            }); 
        } else {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                icon: image,
                map: map
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

}


/*  
jQuery('#myModal1').bind('', function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize');
  map2.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(53.483558, -2.239243));
});
*/

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("a#more").click(function(){
    jQuery("#show-para").toggle();
  });
  jQuery( "#modal1-button" ).click(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
       google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize');
    });
});

</script>
```

From research the problem lies within the fact being in a modal window sets the div and everything inside it (the map) to display none, then when It's displayed again in v3 google maps api it needs to be .resize() 'd. When the "google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize');" is entered into the console it works but for the love of me I cannot get the button click to trigger this.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid any page deign that requires multiple Google maps, otherwise you're burning up your free Google quota and moving more rapidly into payment territory.

Comment: Just so we're covering all the bases here, do all the markers appear when moved outside of the modal?